# Elbow curve response for Normalized vs Standardized data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, normalization, standardization

I was trying K prototypes for a [Blood transfusion dataset](https://github.com/aryancodify/Clustering/blob/master/K-Prototype%2Bclustering.ipynb).
When I tried to find the optimal number of clusters by normalizing(range 0-1) the data it was not giving proper curve, I got the following plot:

[image: Normalized plot]

I used the same method to plot for standardized data(x-mu/sigma) and I got the following:

[image]

Why are we getting such huge difference? I understand that Standardization is preferred normally. But what makes it better?

This is how I'm normalizing in my code. Last column is a categorical variable, So I'm excluding that:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
k_prototype_data = pd.read_csv("transfusion.csv")
normalized_data = normalize(k_prototype_data.iloc[:,:-1])
```

Comment: Can you share how you normalized as well, i.e. your changes to the relevant sections of the original code?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without knowing the details of the analysis and a probably a piece of data themselves, exemplifying the results. Btw, do by "elbow" index you mean SSw (within-cluster-sums-of-squares)?

Comment: @gunes I used the normalize function of sklearn.

Comment: @ttnphns I used the Blood Transfusion dataset which is available as a link in my question and yeah by elbow I mean the Sum Squared Errors

Comment: Can you share your normalisation code?

Comment: @gunes Yeah I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) makes samples unit length, so that each sample is mapped to the unit circle. This is not normalizing the features to 0-1 scale. For that, you can use [min-max scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html). I didn't try out your notebook, but I think the problem will go away.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @gunes. Thanks a lot for your answer. What do you mean by mapped to a unit scaler regarding the normalizer?..I read the docs I'm not quite getting it

Comment: mapping to unit circle/hypersphere means making the sample unit length in L2 norm